# Geocoder Autocomplete limits

Tags: here-api

I have read in Here MAPS FAQs (https://developer.here.com/faqs) this about transactions:

Places autosuggest and Geocoder autocomplete:
**These requests do not count as transactions.**

I don't understand well that, what is the meaning?

Geocoder autocomplete is totally free?

There is any limitation for usage?

Could users send unlimited keystrokes?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you read that right, from the [FAQ](https://developer.here.com/faqs):

> 10. How are HERE Platform transactions counted?
>
> **Places autosuggest and Geocoder autocomplete**
>
> These requests do not count as transactions

Even if they did you would get 250k of them but you can also look through the [Terms and Conditions](https://developer.here.com/terms-and-conditions) where mention is on SLA surrounding them.

There is a blog post that describes how to use the [Geocoder Autcomplete Service with ReactJS](https://developer.here.com/blog/street-address-validation-with-reactjs-and-here-geocoder-autocomplete).  From that post, if you look closely, there are some limits to what useful data is returned in the Autcomplete response.  To be valuable as a solution, you likely will want to follow-up with a request to the Geocoder API with the suggested location ids to get the full data response you might need, not just a list of suggestions.  In that case you do get hit for a transaction on the Geocoder API call.

For example, a search for "4 Yawkey Way" may be 10 HTTP requests to Geocoder Autcomplete and 1 HTTP request to the Geocoder for a total of one transaction.  If you never call the Geocoder API because there is no match, then there is no transaction counted.

I can confirm in my own personal [developer project usage details](https://developer.here.com/projects) report that I do not show any transactions counted against anything other than the final Geocoder request.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that latitude and longitude were not included in the objects returned by autocomplete api. Regards

Comment: The quoted text has been removed from the site. The answer is outdated now. Are you usages still not showing any cost for autocomplete?